# Como capturar o clicar e arrastar de um objeto do DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma div que quero disparar uma função caso o usuário clique e arraste. A div pode ser posicionada em lugares diferentes do grid. Eu uso o gridStack plugin.
Quero obter a posição final da div dentro do grid.

Um objeto do DOM com o gridStack é:

```html
<div data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide"> </div>
```

Os atributos data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0" informam a posição dentro do grid. 
Existe algum evento que capture a posição do objeto depois de clicar e arrastar?

Comment: Não conheço o plugin, mais existe algum evento quando você move a Div? Você pode capturar nele.

Comment: Qual seria o evento de clique e arraste? Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Uma vez usei o sortable. https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Estás urls a presentão uma serie de demostrações http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/demo/
http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/demo/serialization.html